# I have a VBA error 91 only on Mac and not on Windows

Tags: excel, vba, windows, macos, object

Here is my issue: I coded a macro for a friend to help him save time for his job. It works on my machine but not on his and I do not know why. The error he has is: "Error 91", and the debugger points to the line "iCol = s2.Range("1:1").Find(what:=v2, after:=s2.Range("C1")).Column".

Here is the purpose of the macro: identify among his clients the ones who make several demands with increasing prices. So I calculate the variation and then present them horizontally, organized by client and date.

Here is a bit of background: I'm a very new programmer and this is my first VBA project. I did this by trial and error and by piecing together bits of code found here and there.

I work on a windows laptop with Excel 365, my friend is on a Mac with Excel 365.

Here is what I tried: I looked at the type of iCol, which are columns numbers (declared as long). So I do not understand why it would be an object when it is in fact a number. I tried declaring iCol as an object but could not make it work (type mismatch, which I understand because it is indeed a number). I am now stuck and need help please

```
Sub Transpo_dates()
 Sheets("macro_dates2").Cells.Clear
 Sheets("macro_dates_results").Cells.Clear
 Sheets("dates1").Range("a4").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=Sheets("macro_dates2").Range("A1")

 Sheets("macro_dates2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=Range("A1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
 
 Dim last_row As Long
 Dim j As Long
 last_row = Sheets("macro_dates2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 

 Cells(1, 5) = "variations"
 For j = 3 To last_row
 If Cells(j, 1).Value = Cells(j - 1, 1).Value Then
  If Cells(j - 1, 4).Value = "" Then
   Cells(j, 5).Value = 42
  Else
   Cells(j, 5).Value = (Cells(j, 4).Value - Cells(j - 1, 4).Value) / Cells(j - 1, 4).Value
   Cells(j, 5).NumberFormat = "0.0%"
  End If
 End If
Next j

Dim s1 As Worksheet
Dim s2 As Worksheet
Dim N As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim v1 As String
Dim v2 As Date
Dim v3 As Double
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long

Set s1 = Sheets("macro_dates2")
Set s2 = Sheets("macro_dates_results")
N = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 


s1.Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Copy s1.Range("G1")
s1.Range("G1").CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=Range("I1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

s1.Range("G1").CurrentRegion.Copy s1.Range("M1") 'je copie encore
s1.Range("M:M").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo 'suppr doublons noms
s1.Range("M2").CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=Range("M2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes 

s1.Range("M2:M" & N).Copy Destination:=s2.Range("C2") 
s1.Range("I1:I" & N).Copy Destination:=s2.Range("A2") 
s2.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo 

s2.Range("A2:A" & N).Copy 
s2.Range("C1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True 

s2.Range("A2:A" & N).Clear 

For i = 2 To N 
 v1 = s1.Cells(i, 7).Value
 v2 = s1.Cells(i, 9).Value 'dates
 v3 = s1.Cells(i, 11).Value
 iRow = s2.Range("C:C").Find(what:=v1, after:=s2.Range("C1")).Row
 '*** BELOW IS THE LINE POINTED BY THE DEBUGGER/ iCol = ... ***
 iCol = s2.Range("1:1").Find(what:=v2, after:=s2.Range("C1")).Column 
 s2.Cells(iRow, iCol) = v3
 s2.Cells(iRow, iCol).NumberFormat = "0.0%"
Next i


Sheets("macro_dates2").Range("I:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Sheets("macro_dates2").Range("J:J").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Sheets("macro_dates2").Range("O:O").EntireColumn.AutoFit

Sheets("macro_dates2").Range("P:P").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Sheets("macro_dates_results").Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: Just a guess, are the dates formatted the same on both machines? in the second loop... I do know that the Mac uses a different initial calendar start date than pc - would that make a difference?

Comment: @SolarMike thanks for the idea, that could play. I will check that with my friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim result1 as Range, result2 as Range
...
For i = 2 To N 
  ...
  Set result1 = s2.Range("C:C").Find(what:=v1, after:=s2.Range("C1"))
  Set result2 = s2.Range("1:1").Find(what:=v2, after:=s2.Range("C1"))
  'prevent run-time error 91
  If (Not result1 is Nothing) And (Not result2 is Nothing) Then 
    iRow = result1.Row
    iCol = result2.Column 
    s2.Cells(iRow, iCol) = v3
    s2.Cells(iRow, iCol).NumberFormat = "0.0%"
  End If
Next i
```

Comment: thanks for that, I will try it with my friend!